# shut shown a business's website, remove from seach

Tags: seo, search-engines

A business with two partners and a website have parted ways. The website is now just a single static page with contact info for the partners. Searches for these partners still returns this website, before other more relevant results from their new business ventures. Redirects are not a good idea because of the split.

What is the best way to remove the old site from the internet? The question was asked of me in a Google-specific context, but a more general answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take the page down so it returns a 404.  Google will also remove it from their index in time.

Comment: Google has a process for removing pages from their search results: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en